# httpClient GET return type

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

If you take a look to the getData() method it says `this.http.get<Post>`. Is the `<Post>` is specifying the return type, checking the response type, or casting what's coming back

```
interface Post {
      title: string;
      body: string;
    };

    // ...

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getData() {
      this.http.get<Post>(this.url).subscribe(res => {
        this.postTitle = res.title;
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a type hint for the compiler and your IDE of choice. The type will not be checked.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/guide/http.md):

> The HttpClient.get() method parses the JSON server response into the
>   anonymous Object type. It doesn't know what the shape of that object
>   is.
>
> You can tell HttpClient the type of the response to make consuming the
>   output easier and more obvious.

Comment: The [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#httpclientget-returns-response-data) also has some good information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main reason I asked this was because some httpClient tutorials online talk about that doing the casting and checking the shape of the response

Comment: yes, If im not mistaken, if you provide a function signature you can ensure that you are returning the right type of object. So it is consider safer.